# How to include colspan to a table header while web scraping

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am new to web scraping, I am trying to web scrape this website the 2022 Forbes Table  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_in_India ,
but the Rank column and the Forbes Rank column both have colspan - 2
so the number of table header is now - 9 but the info for these table is now - 11 so when I trying to insert the info to their corresponding header I am getting an error (can not set a row with mismatched columns).

So how do I set the colspan for rank and forbes rank?

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_in_India'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html')

soup.find('table')
table = soup.find('table')
titles = table.find_all('th')
Table_Title = [title.text.strip() for title in titles]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = Table_Title)
df

column_data = table.find_all('tr')
column_data

for row in column_data[1:]:
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = individual_row_data 
    print(individual_row_data)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Looks like you could benefit from simply using `df = pd.read_html(url)[0]`. Check out the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to create a `dataframe` and have already included `pandas`, the most elegant solution would be to use [`pandas.read_html()`][1] for scraping the table data:

```
pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_in_India')[0]
```

|  | Rank | Rank.1 | Forbes 2000 rank | Forbes 2000 rank.1 | Name | Headquarters | Revenue (billions US$) | Profit (billions US$) | Assets (billions US$) | Value (billions US$) | Industry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | (0) | 54 | (+1) | Reliance Industries | Mumbai | 86.85 | 7.81 | 192.59 | 228.63 | Conglomerate |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 50 | 51 | (0) | 1759 | (+208) | DMart | Mumbai | 4 | 0.20 | 1.93 | 34.12 | Retail |
| 51 | 52 | (0) | 1759 | (+208) | Adyar Ananda Bhavan | Chennai | 4 | 0.20 | 1.93 | 34.12 | Retail |

---

In alternative you could use your `beautifulsoup` selection and multiply the title by value of `colspan`:

```
Table_Title = []

for title in table.find_all('th'):
    if title.get('colspan'):
        Table_Title.extend([title.get_text(strip=True)]*int(title.get('colspan')))
    else:
        Table_Titlepandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html
```